# PLSQL Code Error Conditional Statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please help identify the error with my following code.

### This is the Error I receive

```
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MYBIRTHDAY" when expecting one of 

the
following:
    := . ( @ % ;
    ORA-06550: line 9, column 33:
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:
    := . ( % ;
    ORA-06550: line 15, column 4:
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
if
```

### This is the code

```
DECLARE 
    myBirthday VARCHAR2(20):= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE ('21-jul-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DAY');
    birthday VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    IF myBirthday = 'FRIDAY' THEN
        birthday := 'Your Birthday is on a FRIDAY';
    ELSEIF (myBirthday = 'SATURDAY') THEN
        birthday := 'Your Birthday is on a SATURDAY';
    ELSEIF (myBirthday = 'SUNDAY') THEN
        birthday := 'Your Birthday is on a SUNDAY';
    ELSE
        birthday := 'Your Birthday is on a Weekday';
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(birthday);
END;
```

Comment: remove brackets from elseif, should work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ELSEIF` use `ELSIF`.

You also need to declare `birthday` so that it is large enough to hold what you try to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you defined:

```
birthday VARCHAR2(20);
```

And you are trying to fill it with more than 20 chars

```
birthday := 'Your Birthday is on a FRIDAY';
           --1                          27
```

Therefore, increase the variable size to about 30 0r 35 char like:

```
 birthday VARCHAR2(35);
```

It should work

EDIT: and as mentioned by @WW. you should use `ELSIF`